# JavaDoc giving fully-qualified class name... how to abbreviate?

Tags: java, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

**Problem**

I'm running `mvn javadoc:javadoc` to generate JavaDoc, and I am pleased with the results, except for one thing: it gives the fully qualified class names for any class coming from a third-party library or our own codebase. For example,

It gives a return type of **com.project.beans.BeanA**, **com.project.beans.BeanB** for methods that return one of these classes.

It gives a param type of **org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject** for a method that takes a JSON object. (Whereas it gives a param type of Integer for a method that takes a java.lang.Integer.)

**Question**

Is there any way to generate the shorthand names for these classes, for readability purposes? i.e. BeanA, BeanB, JSONObject.

And is there a way to do this without any XML configuration?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: This generally happens when you don't have the appropriate `<links>` configuration section in the javadoc plugin configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that what you want is the [`-noqualifier` javadoc option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#noqualifier) which can be set directly from the [`maven javadoc:javadoc`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#noqualifier) command.

Usually to pass the parameter to a maven plugin you just do like for other Java programs using `-D`, in this case it would be `mvn -Dnoqualifier=all javadoc:javadoc` but as far as I can tell the `noqualifier` does not seems to ben set as an expression in the plugin source so I don't really know if you can pass it via the command line.

If it does not work, you can either modify your `pom.xml` and add the `<noqualifier>all</noqualifier>` to the config of the `javadoc` plugin. Or you could create a property in your pom that will be given as a value for the `<noqualifier>` tag, but this time the property can be overridden using the command line.